# Getting JSON Array in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to parse the read array of object into json data from file to loop over it. 
`Out.json` File content

```
[ { id: 10,
    name: 'ProspectJourney',
    details:
     { name: 'ProspectJourney',
       created_at: 1482943640422,
       versioning: null },
    m_id: 1,
    monit: { memory: 192741376, cpu: 0 } },
  { id: 10904,
    name: 'Servicing',
    details:
     { name: 'Servicing',
       created_at: 1482943651962,
       versioning: null },
    m_id: 2,
    monit: { memory: 186843136, cpu: 0 } } ]
```

While i'm able to get the buffer into string and log it out.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const dataPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fs.readFile('Out.json', function(err, data) {
        if (err)
            reject(err);
        else
            resolve(data);
    })
})

dataPromise.then((result) => {
    console.log(result.toString());
})
```

The same is not happening if i try to parse it. Can you tell me what i'm going wrong

Not Working

```
dataPromise.then((result) => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(result.toString()));
})
```

Nodejs version 4.3.1

*Please dont suggest to use any npm module*

Comment: The file doesn't contain valid JSON so you cannot parse it as JSON. In JSON, keys must be quoted and only double quotes are valid to denote strings. http://json.org/example.html .

Comment: also paste the logged data.

Comment: Try to use `require('Out.json')` to avoid `fs`

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you, Got my mistake and what went wrong.. Thanks a lot .. :)

Comment: @RaR .. sure :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to first use JSON.parse() function to parse the json data and then JSON.stringify() to convert the whole data into string format to display wherever you want !

Comment: Please read our community guidelines and how to answer questions

Comment: @ochi definitely i will !! i am a newbie too !!

Comment: instead of having two answers, can you combine them into one? (and then delete the other one) - use the edit link at the bottom of an answer to modify it.  Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

**USERS.JSON**

```
{
   "user1" : {
      "name" : "mahesh",
      "password" : "password1",
      "profession" : "teacher",
      "id": 1
   },
   "user2" : {
      "name" : "suresh",
      "password" : "password2",
      "profession" : "librarian",
      "id": 2
   },
   "user3" : {
      "name" : "ramesh",
      "password" : "password3",
      "profession" : "clerk",       
      "id": 3
   }
}
```

**Code**

```
      var express = require('express');
            var app = express();
        var fs = require("fs");

    app.get('/listUsers', function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + "/" + "users.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {


        console.log(data);
        res.end(data);
    });
})
```

Comment: this may (or may not) answer the question but w/o any explanations as to what it does, it is hard for newbies to figure out why this is a good answer.  Please add code comments or some form of brief explanations for the benefit of the community

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @FelixKling in the comments, your JSON is invalid:

1. The keys must be in double quotes
2. Single quotes must be replaced by double-quotes

The reason you are not seeing this in your output is because your Promise doesn't have a `.catch` (see below for an example of one).

One way to get your program to work is to perform a global replace on single quotes with double quotes AND quote your keys as follows:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const dataPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
fs.readFile('Out.json', function(err, data) {
    if (err)
        reject(err);
    else
        resolve(data);
    })
})

dataPromise.then((result) => {
  let jsonStr = result.toString();

  // PUT THE KEYS IN DOUBLE QUOTES AND REPLACE SINGLE QUOTES WITH DOUBLE QUOTES
  jsonStr = jsonStr.replace(/(\w*):/g, function(match, key, offset, string){
    return `"${key}":`;
  }).replace(/'/g, '"');

  // YOU CAN SEE WHAT THE REPLACED STRING LOOKS LIKE IF YOU UNCOMMENT THE LINE BELOW
  // console.log("Converted String: \n" + jsonStr);

  console.log("Parse JSON and print it:");
  console.log(JSON.parse(jsonStr));
})
.catch(err => {
  // PRINT OUT THE ERROR THAT OCCURRED IN THE PROMISE
  console.log(err);
});
```